# Different content for different users in Joomla

Tags: joomla, web, content-management-system

I'm developing a CMS website for handling work reports. The goal is simple in principle: My company do a job for another company and we use this website to have a repository of every message and documents we can possibly share.

So, I upload reports to the webiste and then my client logs in and see every report and message made for him.

I'm developing this site on Joomla but I don't have a clue about how to manage different reports for different users. I don't want to have a different website for each user, I just want the list of documents and messages to be different.

Is there a simple way to do this? I'm open to every possibility, even if it includes building the webiste with another tool other than joomla.

Thanks in advance.
PS: I'm so sorry if the question is too general but I'm in a hurry.

Answer (score 1):

What i would do is the following (as long as the number of users is not unlimited)....

When a user is created he is assigned to a group.

Then have a page where multiple articles appear (like a Category Blog Layout) (documents with attachments and anything else can appear here) where each document is viewed/accessed only by a certain group.

In this way you will have a central place where all articles-documents reside but each of these articles are accessible only to users belonging to the right group.

Comment: I think it should work, and I believe I can count on the fact that users are limited (these are real clients so they won't be signing up to the system at a fast pace). Thanks for your answer!